# WPBakery post content inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ajax

In a wordpress page I have a list of posts, each one links to a Bootstrap Modal where I want to load the post content.

This is my PHP function (inside a custom plugin).
Gets the post ID and return content.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_obra', 'getObraAJAX');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_obra', 'getObraAJAX');

function getObraAJAX(){
    $post = get_post($_GET['id']);
    WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    echo $content;
    die();
}
```

This is my JS conde.
Gets AJAX response and put it inside the modal.

```
function getObra(id) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "'.get_site_url().'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_obra&id="+id,
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function( response ) {
            $(".modal-body").html(response);
            $("#obraModal").modal("show");
        });

}
```

The posts are made with WPBakery and includes a carouser [vc_images_carousel] but the modal shows all the images, not a carousel.

I assume I need to run some JS to "build" the carousel but I don't know how.

You can see the page here http://puchetaconstrucciones.com.ar/obras-2/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
The page was missing vc_carousel.min.css transition.min.js and vc_carousel.min.js
With these files loaded, the corousel works fine